# Get kotlin class failed with string but works with constant - on dynamic feature

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I just call a method class through this line :

```kotlin
val instance = Class.forName(nameClass).kotlin.objectInstance
```

When I set the nameClass with a constant value (see below) it's work.

```kotlin
private const val PROVIDER_CLASS = "com.abc.xyz.feature.DynamicFeatureImpl\$Provider"

fun method() {
    val instance = Class.forName(PROVIDER_CLASS).kotlin.objectInstance
}
```

But, when I set the nameClass to string (not constant), like this

```kotlin
fun method() {
    val nameClass = "com.abc.xyz.feature.DynamicFeatureImpl\$Provider"
    val instance = Class.forName(nameClass).kotlin.objectInstance
}
```

it's not work and throw **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**.
[image: ClassNotFoundException]

I have trying make log, check is the value PROVIDER_CLASS are same with the string nameClass, and the result is **true**. but the code not work with string one.
My goal is make the code work through variable className string as parameter.

So, what wrong with the code?
it's make me confused.

**Update:**
Actually it's call a method from dynamic feature with dagger. my reference [this medium post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/patterns-for-accessing-code-from-dynamic-feature-modules-7e5dca6f9123)

Comment: Both snippets look correct, and work in my testing. How exactly does that last  snippet not work for you? Do you have an error message or a stacktrace?

Comment: @zsmb13 i just add the screenshoot of ClassNotFoundException

Comment: actually it's load dynamic feature, also using dagger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding rules to **proguard-rules.pro** on root project

```
-keep class com.abc.xyz.feature.DynamicFeatureImpl {
   com.abc.xyz.feature.DynamicFeatureImpl$Provider Provider;
}

-keep class com.abc.xyz.feature.DynamicFeatureImpl$Provider {   
   *;
}
```

the rules that I've added before is only on consumer-rules (the dynamic module) but in fact it's not enough

```
-keep class com.abc.xyz.feature.** { *; }
-keep class com.abc.xyz.feature.di.** { *; }
```

It's make me confused a couple days, hope this will help somebody if find this issue.